# User's location using corelocationframework is not working without wifi

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am beginner in Ios and in my project i am using CLLocationManager for getting current location but when i turn off "Wifi" and i Enable the GPS service but current location is not displaying with out internet it's showing error message how can we get current location using GPs with out internet (i am using i pad for testing this app)

### my code is below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

   locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

   locationManager.delegate = self;

    if([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]){

        NSUInteger code = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

        if (code == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined && ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)] || [locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])) {



            if([[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription"]){
                [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

                [locationManager setDistanceFilter:10.0f];
                [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters];

            }

            else if([[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription"]) {
                [locationManager  requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

                [locationManager setDistanceFilter:10.0f];
                [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters];

            } else {
                NSLog(@"Info.plist does not contain NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription or NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription");
            }
        }
    }

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    }

    NSLog(@"Resolving the Address");

    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);

        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {

            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];

            adressLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n%@\n%@",
                                 placemark.subThoroughfare, placemark.thoroughfare,
                                 placemark.postalCode, placemark.locality,
                                 placemark.administrativeArea,
                                 placemark.country];
        }

        else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }

    } ];

}
```

Comment: Only the iPad with GSM modem has a GPS receiver. All other iPads are WiFi only and will therefor not give back a location when the WiFi is turned off

Comment: i am not understand what your saying

Comment: If your iPad is a WiFi only model, as in it has not support for a simcard to use the mobile network it does not have GPS. It uses WiFi to get its location.

Comment: No my i pad having GPS antenna i already keep that (Local service) at on mode but my i pad there is no facility for inserting sim card

Comment: If your iPad is not the WiFi+Cellular model then it has **NO** GPS support. Thus when you turn of the WiFi it will not be able to find a location.

Comment: No rckoenes our previous employees already done few apps using this i pad and my i pad is WIfi+Cellular model one and is there any mi-stack in my code please guide me

Comment: Well only now you are telling that you have you have a WiFi+Cellular model, also there are many spelling mistaks that make you post very hard to read. it iPad and not i pas and mistake and mi-stake. What I'm missing your code where you request the GPS access.

Comment: sorry for my spelling mistacks is thre no solution for this

Comment: Yes you need to request access to the users location, call `requestAlwaysAuthorization`

Comment: in my above code i am clearly calling requestAlwaysAuthorization if you don't mind please re write my code and post it please if there is any errors

Answer (score 0):

Add a line in the app's info.plist file, that says: `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`, it should fix your problem.

Comment: my i pad having GPS anteena facility and i already keep that(Local services)at on mode in my i pad

Comment: i already add that NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in info.plist

Comment: no i am getting current location only when wifi turn on mode is there any mi stack in my code please guide me